# Don't understand this "object not callable" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I am setting up unit tests and when trying to call a function, `Pt2D`, I am getting the error `TypeError: 'Pt2D' object is not callable`.

I have tried all other solutions on the first couple pages when searching up the problem. The two programs are in separate files and I am importing the first class.

```
class Pt2D(object):
    """Straightforward 2D point class.
    Args:
        x (float, optional): The initial x-coordinate. Defaults to 0.
        y (float, optional): The initial y-coordinate. Defaults to 0.
    """

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):



class TestPt2D(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.geo = Pt2D()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_stuff(self):
        y1value = self.geo(0)
        y2value = self.geo(1)
        ymidvalue = self.geo(0.5)
```

I am expecting the code to work but I can't get around the error.

Comment: As provided, your code won't run because the empty `__init__` is a `SyntaxError`. What's inside that `__init__`?

Comment: actually in addition to that the self.geo() items are incorrect.  geo is an instance.  method call on an instance is not valid with code there.  you would want to call some method that the Pt2D objects provide.

Comment: Don't try to call the Pt2D object. What do you expect `self.geo(0)` to do anyway?

Comment: I changed self.geo(0) to self.geo[0] and it's running but I'm not sure why. But what I am using it for is to use 'self.assertEqual' for it.

Answer (score 1):

Populate your `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```

Comment: Given the code they provided, this will help but doesn't solve their problem - the code in `test_stuff()` doesn't make any sense with only an `__init__` defined.